# Identifying clauses (including finite and non finite) and analysing internal structure of the clauses

Tags: phrase-structure, clauses, phrases, grammatical-subject, grammatical-object

An example of how to do this is from the sentence
"I was on holiday, but when I saw the pictures I went straight away"

I / was / on holiday

S:NP / V / SC:PP

but / when I saw the pictures / I / went / straight away

CC / A:FC                   / S:NP / V / A:AdvP

when / I / saw / the pictures

CS S:NP V DO:NP

I'm struggling with identifying finite verbs, non finite verbs and it just feels like there are so many ways to split up the sentence, can anyone give some tips into identifying such things?